# NullPointerException when calling a cursor using contentprovider

Tags: android, android-fragments, cursor, android-contentprovider

i'm keep getting NullPointerException when calling a cursor. 
the db is filled in FragmentList where there is a cursor adapter and the list is shown, then when pressing one of the items main activity calls FragmentDetails  to show info from the db about the selected item.

FragmentDetails :

```
public class FragmentDetails extends Fragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

private static Context mContext;     

public static FragmentDetails newInstance(long id){

    Uri uri = PlacesContract.Places.CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri,null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
```

Mainactivity:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(long id) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom,
            R.anim.slide_out_to_bottom, R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom,
            R.anim.slide_out_to_bottom);
    Fragment detailsFragment = FragmentDetails.newInstance(id);
```

LogCat:

```
01-08 14:11:17.489: E/AndroidRuntime(2005): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 14:11:17.489: E/AndroidRuntime(2005): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-08 14:11:17.489: E/AndroidRuntime(2005):     at com.lora_solomon.myfavoriteplaces.view.FragmentDetails.newInstance(FragmentDetails.java:57)
E/AndroidRuntime(2005):     at com.lora_solomon.myfavoriteplaces.view.MainActivity.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(2005):     at com.lora_solomon.myfavoriteplaces.view.FragmentList.onItemClick(FragmentList.java:113)
E/AndroidRuntime(2005):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
E/AndroidRuntime(2005):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
01-08 14:11:17.489: E/AndroidRuntime(2005):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2855)
01-08 14:11:17.489: E/AndroidRuntime(2005):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3529)
01-08 14:11:17.489: E/AndroidRuntime(2005):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-08 14:11:17.489: E/AndroidRuntime(2005):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-08 14:11:17.489: E/AndroidRuntime(2005):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-08 14:11:17.489: E/AndroidRuntime(2005):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-08 14:11:17.489: E/AndroidRuntime(2005):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 14:11:17.489: E/AndroidRuntime(2005):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-08 14:11:17.489: E/AndroidRuntime(2005):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-08 14:11:17.489: E/AndroidRuntime(2005):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-08 14:11:17.489: E/AndroidRuntime(2005):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

any help will be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

From the code you posted it doesn't look like mContext is initialized. I'm guessing that's your null pointer exception.

I need to point out that keeping a static reference to a context is not a good idea and can keep activities or services in memory past the end of their lifecycle.  Instead you may want to move the query into the fragment's onCreate method or pass in a context as an argument to newInstance.

If you'd like an overview of contexts and some their possible pitfalls, I thought this article was pretty good:
http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/

Comment: i thought this is the problem. but i could not find a way to initiate it. i will have a look at the article, tx for the reference.